# How can I fill a vector with another smaller vector in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, c++11, stl

I want to fill a `std::vector` with another `vector` . For example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> src = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> dst(9);
```

I want to fill dst to make it become: `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3`

Is there an efficient method to do this?

I have two methods now:

The first is two loop:

```cpp
auto size = dst.size() / src.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int val : src) {
        dst.emplace_back(val);
    }
}
```

Or use the `std::copy` in one loop.

Maybe exist a more efficient method?

Comment: std::copy_n with a loop can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the question. With `std::vector<int> dst(9);` and the shown code you get an infinit loop.

[std::vector::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

```
std::vector<int> dst;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    dst.insert(dst.end(), src.begin(), src.end());
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code `std.insert`.

Comment: yep, the shown code is infinit loop, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Computing the remainder each time may be inefficient...?
(But, size of `dst` does not have to be a multiple of the size of `src`.)

```cpp
std::vector<int> src = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> dst(9);
{
    int i=0;
    std::generate( dst.begin(), dst.end(), [&i,&src]()->int{    return src[(i++)%src.size()];   } );
}
```

Comment: Oh, I just realized I was posting `3`. Modified. Thank you.

Comment: A hack method, I'll learn the `std::generate` later.

Answer (score 1):

How about this version that uses iterators instead of indices:

```
std::vector<int> src = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> dst(9);

for (auto i = dst.begin(), e = dst.end(); i != e;)
{
    i = std::copy_n(src.begin(),
           std::min(src.size(), std::size_t(e - i)), i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `range-v3` library, example:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  using namespace ranges;
  std::vector<int> src = {1, 2, 3};
  std::vector<int> dst =
      views::repeat(src) | views::take(3) | views::join | to<std::vector>();
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xTrr1o5cr)</kbd>

i.e `repeat` `src`, `take` 3 of them, `join` the `views`, convert to `vector`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::copy_n` from `<algorithm>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> src = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> dst(9);

    const size_t times = dst.size() / src.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        std::copy_n(src.begin(), src.size(), dst.begin() + i * src.size());
    }

    for (int x : dst) std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```